# MISRA C:2012 Rule 14.4

Tags: c, misra

As per the MISRA rule 
The controlling expression of an if statement and the controlling expression of an iteration-statement shall have essentially Boolean type

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(void){
    int i = 0;

    if(i){}              /* Non-compliant - int32_t is not boolean */

    if(i != 0){}         /* Compliant */

}
```

I am not able to understand how can it lead to a problem to use just the value .Why with if only adding a boolean expression is treated as good practise .
Any insight will be helpful

Comment: The link you gave only works if you have an account there.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thanks removed the link anways have the example in OP

Comment: It is too easy to forget ! and not notice.  Too skinny.  A debate about it here isn't going to change the rule.

Comment: @HansPassant its not really for the change for rule but insight

Comment: This is for me one of the big problem in the design of C.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rationale is provided with the rule: strong typing. The controlling expression should be essentially boolean type. The result of the equality, relational etc operators is to be regarded as essentially boolean, whereas showing in an `int` or pointer without an operator means that the expression is of the used type.

(As a side-note, this may be important for compatibility with C++ where a lot of operators actually return a `bool`, and may be overloaded with an `operator` function returning `bool`.)

The main reason is however not provided by MISRA, and that is self-documenting code. `if(ptr != NULL)` can only be a comparison of a pointer against NULL. No room for misunderstandings. `if(ptr)` could either be a comparison against NULL, or it could be an accidental slip of the finger and the programmer actually meant `if(*ptr)`. Also, if the pointer has some cryptic name, it isn't obvious what `if(xyz)` does, but it is obvious what `if(xyz != NULL)` is.

This rule also prevents bugs such as `if(func)` where `if(func())` was intended. Keep in mind that a lot of the MISRA rules are there for the benefit of a static analyser.

---

Regarding strong typing, consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (void)
{
  int x = false;
  x = ~x;

  if(x)
  {
    puts("x is true");
    if(x!=true)
    {
      puts("but x is not true\n");
    }
  }

  bool y = x;

  if(y)
  {
    puts("y is true");
    if(y==true)
    {
      puts("I swear, y is really true");
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
x is true
but x is not true

y is true
I swear, y is really true
```

Comment: `int x = ~false;` for more fun at party

Comment: @Stargateur Feel free to replace it with your personal favourite, non-zero integer constant.

Answer (score 4):

> Why with if only adding a boolean expression is treated as good practise?

*"MISRA-C introduces a strong typing model to help users avoid unexpected issues which occur in the C typing model.
The rule prevents the accidental use of integer expression when a boolean expression was intended.
"* as [stated in the MISRA forum, as an "official" MISRA C WG answer](https://www.misra.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=228&t=1656#p3367)

> How can it lead to a problem to just use a integer in a if statement?

There is no way I can think of, but enforcing a consistent code style and philosophy in a project is important too.

Comment: Are there compiler options to enable MISRA-C violation warnings?

Comment: There are tools, that check if your code is MISRA-C compliant, however I think they are mostly proprietary

Comment: @FiddlingBits A few compilers like embedded systems IAR support MISRA plug-ins. The most common however, is to use an external MISRA checker/static analyser. Unfortunately they are all quite expensive and of diverse quality.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a particular reason.

I was thinking in the line of type conversions, where e.g. with a double `d` things could go wrong, but the double will be evaluated to be/not be 0.0 and so still is a valid expression for an if or iteration statement. Or a pointer to a character (string), but there too it will yield a valid expression.

So the only reason I can come up with is that it is now clear it is a boolean expression, i.e. better readability.

It would be good if MISRA would also check for the proper second operand, for example

```
char *s;
if (s != NULL && *s != '\0')
```

which could also have been written as:

```
if (s != 0 && *s != 0)
```

and for the double `d`:

```
if (d != 0.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

One other possible reason could be to identify potential bugs like this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(void){
    int i = 0;

    if(i){}              /* Non-compliant - int32_t is not boolean */

    if(i |= 0){}         /* Non-compliant - type is still int32_t */

}
```

or the more obvious

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(void){
    int i = 0;

    if(i){}              /* Non-compliant - int32_t is not boolean */

    if(i = 0){}         /* Non-compliant */

}
```